# why my chrome did not send the cookie i set

Tags: java, http, cookies

My problem is as the title , and I programmed with Java, following is my code

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("shikaiwenCookie","sended");
cookie.setMaxAge(2000);
cookie.setDomain("/bbs");
```

[image]

this is the information I get from my HTTP monitor. It seems that cookie has been send to the browser. But when I submit my form, the browser did not send the cookie to my server. Could someone help me ? Thanks in advance .

Comment: Probably, because it should be "sent", not "sended" ;-) Or because  `/bbs` is a strange value for *domain*.

Comment: ok ,how to set the domain attr of cookie normally, can you give me an example?

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't be setting domain at all? Because I doubt you need "bbs domain". And, as @ljgw points out, `/bbs` sounds more like path.

Comment: it didn't works ,even if i remove the domain

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing `domain` with `path`. Try `setPath("/bbs")`.

edit:

both the domain and path are used to determine if the cookie is relevant for the request. The domain focusses on the domainname in the URL, and the path must `path-match` with the path of the url. As an example: the url `http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19489484` has domain `stackoverflow.com` and path `/posts/19489484`. Here the cookie path `/posts` would path-match with the path in the url.

Comment: yes,you are so greate ,that's the problem . as you said ,i am confused with domain and path , can you explain it breifly ? thanks

Comment: I added a brief example to my answer. Hope it helps!